# wxpython and py2exe not working

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython

I am having lots of trouble trying to compile a wxpython application into an exe file.  py2exe keeps giving me errors and won't compile my code to an exe.  The following is what happens when I run a simple setup.py script.  I am on windows 64 bit and python 2.7 and using py2exe 64 bit.  (bundling does not work in 64 bit py2exe. not sure if that poses a problem) I believe I have all the right DLLs installed since I have microsoft visual studio installed.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
*** searching for required modules ***
*** parsing results ***
creating python loader for extension 'P4API' (C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\P4AP
I.pyd -> P4API.pyd)
creating python loader for extension 'wx._misc_' (C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\
wx-2.8-msw-unicode\wx\_misc_.pyd -> wx._misc_.pyd)
creating python loader for extension 'select' (C:\Python27\DLLs\select.pyd -> se
lect.pyd)
creating python loader for extension 'unicodedata' (C:\Python27\DLLs\unicodedata
.pyd -> unicodedata.pyd)
creating python loader for extension 'wx._windows_' (C:\Python27\lib\site-packag
es\wx-2.8-msw-unicode\wx\_windows_.pyd -> wx._windows_.pyd)
creating python loader for extension 'wx._core_' (C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\
wx-2.8-msw-unicode\wx\_core_.pyd -> wx._core_.pyd)
creating python loader for extension 'wx._gdi_' (C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\w
x-2.8-msw-unicode\wx\_gdi_.pyd -> wx._gdi_.pyd)
creating python loader for extension 'wx._controls_' (C:\Python27\lib\site-packa
ges\wx-2.8-msw-unicode\wx\_controls_.pyd -> wx._controls_.pyd)
creating python loader for extension 'bz2' (C:\Python27\DLLs\bz2.pyd -> bz2.pyd)

*** finding dlls needed ***
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 4, in <module>
    setup(windows=['PerforceApp.py'])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\build_exe.py", line 243, in run
    self._run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\build_exe.py", line 305, in _run
    dlls = self.find_dlls(extensions)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\build_exe.py", line 389, in find_dl
ls
    self.dll_excludes)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\build_exe.py", line 1064, in find_d
ependend_dlls
    bin_depends(loadpath, images + [sys.executable], excludes_use)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\build_exe.py", line 1441, in bin_de
pends
    if isSystemDLL(dll):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\build_exe.py", line 1498, in isSyst
emDLL
    raise Exception, "Seems not to be an exe-file"
Exception: Seems not to be an exe-file
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem that was caused by the "MSVCP90.dll" file, so i added this directive to my setup.py and now it works like a charm!

```
dll_excludes = ['MSVCP90.dll']
```